# how to make body tag elastic?

Tags: css

```
<body>
<div id="div01"></div>
<div id="div02"></div>
<img id="img01" src="...">
</body>
```

css

```
body{
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:gold;
}
```

`div01`, `div02` and `img01` are `100px`, `200px` and `300px` width, respectively.

The width of body's children is dynamically changed.

How can I set elastic width of the body, according to largest child ?  Without using javascript, just pure css.

For example, if `img01` becomes `250px` `body` should be `250px`. If `div01` becomes `400px` `body` should be `400px`. And still staying horizontally centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against using the `<body>` as a variable width element - the standard method is a wrapper `<div>`. For example:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100" />
    [ other variable width content ]
  </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
#wrap{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/Teq6N/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be:

```
body {
    width: auto;
}
```

This tells your browser to calculate your `body`'s size accordingly to the size of its inner elements.
You can see more documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp